# How can I annotate f(*params)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, typing, argument-unpacking

I cannot work out how to correctly annotate this code:

```
from typing import Iterable

def f(*params: Iterable) -> str:
    return ":".join(params)
```

I know that `Iterable` is incorrect, because mypy tells me:

```
error: Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type Tuple[Iterable[Any], ...]; expected Iterable[str]
```

… but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When annotations are combined with `*args`-style argument lists, the annotation specifies the type of *each argument expected*. As stated in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values):

> Arbitrary argument lists can as well be type annotated, so that the
>   definition:
>
> ```
> def foo(*args: str, **kwds: int): ...
> ```
>
> is acceptable and it means that, e.g., all of the following represent
>   function calls with valid types of arguments:
>
> ```
> foo('a', 'b', 'c')
> foo(x=1, y=2)
> foo('', z=0)
> ```
>
> In the body of function `foo`, the type of variable `args` is deduced as
>   `Tuple[str, ...]` and the type of variable `kwds` is `Dict[str, int]`.

In your example, since `params` is expected to be a tuple of strings, the correct annotation is `str`:

```
def f(*params: str) -> str:
    return ":".join(params)
```